# Where clause in LINQ query doesn't evaluate against data

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I'm populating an `ObservableCollection` with the following statement:

```
foreach (var customer in
    collListItem.Select(
        item =>
        new
            {
                ResourceName = item["Resource_x0020_Name"].ToString(),
                Quantity = (item["Quantity_x0020_Ordered"] ?? 0).ToString(),
                CustomerName = item["Title"].ToString()
        })
        .Select(r => new Customer { ResourceName = r.ResourceName, Quantity = int.Parse(r.Quantity) })
        .Where(r => r.CustomerName == "test"))
{
    resources.Add(customer);
}
```

When I remove the `.Where()` portion of my LINQ query the statement will fetch all customers. I would like to restrict this to a customer I specify. Whenever I specify a customer in the `where` clause it doesn't appear to evaluate properly. I'm sure my problem is syntactical but after referring to the LINQ documentation I'm a bit unsure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: When you say doesn't appear to evaluate properly; what exactly does it do?

Comment: @Tom Nothing returns even though I have an Item["Title"] with 'test' in the data (tested with MessageBox and it's used in populating another datagrid).

Comment: @Codingo That's because you're not setting `CustomerName` on your `Customer` class. You're setting it on the anonymous object only. You need to do both.

Comment: Added an example to my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two calls to `Select`. The first one projects the original collection to a collection of dynamic objects with three properties (`ResourceName`, `Quantity`, and `CustomerName`). Then your second call to `Select` projects that collection into another collection of `Customer` instances, but only two properties of that class are set (`ResourceName` and `Quantity`). You are not setting `CustomerName` in the second select therefore it is uninitialized when `Where` is called.

I think you really just want one call to `Select`, which combines the two calls and skips creating of the dynamic objects.

For example:

```
foreach (var customer in
    collListItem.Select(
        item =>
        new Customer {
                ResourceName = item["Resource_x0020_Name"].ToString(),
                Quantity = (item["Quantity_x0020_Ordered"] ?? 0),
                CustomerName = item["Title"].ToString()
        }
    )
    .Where(r => r.CustomerName == "test"))
{
    resources.Add(customer);
}
```

I'm assuming that `item["Quantity_x0020_Ordered"]` is already an integer since you have it combined with an integer via the `??` operator. Therefore there's no need for the `ToString` call from the first select or the `int.Parse` call from the second.

Comment: Helped me to solve the problem but I'm a bit unsure how I could combine this into one select (my knowledge doesn't stretch that far yet!). I don't suppose you could provide an example?

Comment: @Codingo in the first select, instead of `new { `, just use `new Customer { `, then delete the second select entirely. You'll also need to move the `int.Parse()` for quantity

Comment: @Rob Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Just switch the last `Select` with the `Where`

```
foreach (var customer in
    collListItem.Select(
        item =>
        new
            {
                ResourceName = item["Resource_x0020_Name"].ToString(),
                Quantity = (item["Quantity_x0020_Ordered"] ?? 0).ToString(),
                CustomerName = item["Title"].ToString()
            })
        .Where(r => r.CustomerName == "test")
        .Select(r => new Customer { ResourceName = r.ResourceName, Quantity = int.Parse(r.Quantity) }))
{
    resources.Add(customer);
}
```

or collapse it like this

```
resources.AddRange(collListItem
    .Where(item => item["Title"].ToString() == "test")
    .Select(item =>
        new Customer {
            ResourceName = item["Resource_x0020_Name"].ToString(),
            Quantity = item["Quantity_x0020_Ordered"] ?? 0
        }
     )
 );
```

You always want to query first (`Where` before `Select`) because `Select` actually creates an entirely new array each time, and it can be expensive to do so, so you want to make sure you do that with the least amount of items as possible, by using all the queries first, so that you have all the items you need first then you can create the array.